# Compatibility, advantages less css

Tags: css, cross-browser, less

For my website, I'm considering using [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Can I have some problem of compatibility in browser, problem with JavaScript or other problems? I know that is better than CSS but I don't know if I can have problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I prefer [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) over [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (better syntax [loops and control structures] and it has some more capabilities => my opinion), **it's generally a good idea to use a CSS-Framework**. It safes time and unneccesary work. Just be sure to precompile your styles in Production mode. Don't do it clientside (might cause problems: disabled javascript, performance-issues...). If you precompile the CSS, you don't have to fear any problems, since native CSS gets delivered to the browser.

You can take a look at a good comparison here:

https://gist.github.com/820035

Comment: Thanks I'll try SASS too. Ok form now i'll use a CSS-Framework for my website

Answer (score 1):

from the LESS docs:

> As an extension to CSS, LESS is not only backwards compatible with CSS, but the extra features it adds use existing CSS syntax. [...] if in doubt, lets you fall back to CSS.

The best approach in production is to server-side compile it, while in development you can simply use the client-side javascript compiler:

http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage

also note that LESS is not strictly a framework (opposite of what Twitter Bootstrap is) but can easily be paired to one. Bootstrap itself has a LESS-enhanced version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Christoph. I prefer SASS too. Also Less or Sass aren't used to browser compatibility. They are used to add functionality to css.

You can look at that article here.

http://nittygrittyjs.com/blog/why-less-is-a-pain-in-the-sass/